# how to set the size of a absolutelayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to make a absolutelayout in the corner of the screen,and set the size of it:widhtrequest=60 and heightrequest =60

inside the absolute is a frame and label.

but it seems the absolutelayout is autosized according the Image size inside it.

How can I size it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absLayout">
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="box" BackgroundColor="Blue"   WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" >
            <Image BackgroundColor="Olive"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0, 50, 50" Source="test.jpg"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```