# I can not specify a Height of a customView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a CustomView to use in CollectionView's DataTemplate

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
            <Image Source="image1.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"></Image>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#fedb0a" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,0.426,0.1177" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HasShadow="False">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.682,0.29,AutoSize,0.05885">
                    <Label Text="Hi" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#95000000" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="20" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0">
                        <Image Source="icon1.png" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"></Image>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="hopeshow~" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#fedb0a"></Label>
                    <Label Text="2020 year" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Frame>
```

I placed it in my DataTemplate `<vi:MyCustomView HeightRequest="40"></vi:MyCustomView>` but it seems that the HeightRequest is not sequenced.
the view autosized a large view.

The WidthRequest is ok when I set a value.

How to do with it?

Comment: Try to set the HeightRequest of Frame .

Comment: It worked and I have set the HeightRequest of the Frame but it seems make nosence

Comment: What is the means of nosence?

Comment: The height of the view is very large and no matter what value I set it is the same height

Comment: Can you share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: This is all the code you can create a ContentView with the code and display it in the MainPage

Comment: Did you solve the issue here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721968/how-to-set-the-size-of-a-absolutelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout like **StackLayout** and **AbsoluteLayout**  will not fit the size of its child elements . So if you want to implement it you can use `Grid` instead of them .

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 //set them in the same Row and Column and they will be in the same position .
  <Image Source="image1.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
  <Frame BackgroundColor="#fedb0a" HasShadow="False"Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
   //...
  </Frame>

  //...other elements

</Grid>
```

For more details about layout you can check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid